# How to display a warning message until user tick at least one checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some checkboxes on the website. If user doesn't tick any of the checkboxes I want to display a warning text on the page (not alert). Once one of the checkboxes ticked this warning will disappear. I wrote following code. This help me to display only on console. However, I want to get some help to display on page itself. Any help is appreciated! PS: I am pretty new in this. Sorry if my question is stupid.

```
<script>
var array1 = []
const checkboxes=document.querySelectorAll('input[name=group1]:checked')
for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
array1.push(checkboxes[i].value)
}
if(array1.length == 0){
console.log("Please select at least one option to process further!")
}    
</script>
```

Comment: Using some of the suggested answers you should have a listeners event and modify your results as needed, so having the warning div you can hide/unhide it when certain factors occur.

Answer (score 2):

You add something like `<div id="warning"></div>` in your html.

And

```
document.querySelector('#warning').innerText = 'Please select at least one option';
```

in your javascript. Just play around with it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Actually I did what you said and I can see the message on the webpage once no checkboxes is ticked. However, when I tick one of the checkboxes warning doesn't disappear. Even if I can see the selected checkboxes on local storage. It only disappear when I move to the next page and come back to the actual page. Do you have any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: You need to listen for events that suggest a reset has been made, to remove the message. You could run a timeout function that makes the message vanish and reset this timeout every call for warning.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you have something basically like this in your HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="5">
<div id="warningDiv">Please select at least one option to process further!</div>
```

At this point you just need to do something like this:

```
<script>
    if(document.querySelectorAll('input[name=group1]:checked').length == 0)
    {
        //Here you can do an alert or put the text on another html element like a div 
        //For example
        alert("Please select at least one option to process further!")
    }
</script>
```

The ":checked" is telling the selector to only return the ones that are selected. And the querySelectorAll returns an array of nodes, so you can easily check is lenght to verify is any was selected.

You can play along it if you want to validate one selected, two selected, more than one, etc.

If you paint the message into another element you need to add an else to remove the message.

```
<script>
    if(document.querySelectorAll('input[name=group1]:checked').length == 0)
    {
        //Here you can do an alert or put the text on another html element like a div 
        //For example
        document.getElementById('warningDiv').innerHTML = "Please select at least one option to process further!";
    }else{
        document.getElementById('warningDiv').innerHTML = "";
    }
</script>
```

As suggested you can put this into an listener, more or less like this:

```js
function checkChecked()
{
    if(document.querySelectorAll('input[name=group1]:checked').length == 0)
     {
          document.getElementById('warningDiv').innerHTML = "Please select at least one option to process further!";
     }else{
          document.getElementById('warningDiv').innerHTML = "";
     }

}

checkChecked();

const allcheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=group1]');
    for(let checkboxinput in allcheckboxes)
    {
        if(typeof allcheckboxes[checkboxinput] == "object" && allcheckboxes[checkboxinput] != null)
        {
          allcheckboxes[checkboxinput].addEventListener('change', function(e) {
            checkChecked()
          });
        }
    }
```

```css
#warning {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="5">
<div id="warningDiv">Please select at least one option to process further!</div>
```

Comment: OP mentions in question that `alert()` is not an option.

Comment: Just noted, added the other version too

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and time. It really helped!

Comment: Glad to hear! Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

```js
// query and get elements
const checkboxs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
const messages = document.querySelectorAll('.warning');

// add event listener to each element
checkboxs.forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener("click", () => {
    toggle(checkboxs, messages);
  });
});

// show controlled elements
const show = (elems) => {
  elems.forEach(elem =>
    elem.style.display = 'block'
  );
};

// hide controlled elements
const hide = (elems) => {
  elems.forEach(elem =>
    elem.style.display = 'none'
  );
};

// toggle controlled element visibility according to checkbox state
const toggle = (checkboxs, controlled) => {
  const emptys = [].filter.call(checkboxs, el => !el.checked);
  if (emptys.length == checkboxs.length) {
    show(controlled);
  } else {
    hide(controlled);
  }
};
```

```css
.warning {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' value='1'>
<input type='checkbox' value='2'>
<input type='checkbox' value='3'>
<input type='checkbox' value='4'>
<p class='warning'>Please select at least one option to process further!</p>
```

Comment: After going to the next page and coming back to this page, even if two of the boxes are checked there is still warning message. How can I fix it?

Comment: @A.A. You can execute `toggle(checkboxs, messages);` on page load